# How to make the product of two lenses?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

If I have two lenses:

```
foo :: Lens' X Foo
bar :: Lens' X Bar
```

Is there a way to construct a product lens:

```
foobar :: Lens' X (Foo, Bar)
foobar = ... foo bar
```

or is it impossible?

Answer (score 11):

In general case, this is impossible. Probably the most common case when you have lenses to different fields of the record, the lenses are disjoint, so you can make a lawful lens. But in general it's not true. This is why the combinator is not provided in the libraries, even it would be easy to write.

Assume `lensProd` exists. It's enough to take the same lens twice:

```
_1 :: Lens' (a, b) a -- Simpler type

badLens :: Lens' (a, b) (a, a)
badLens = lensProd _1 _1
```

Then the "You get back what you put in" law doesn't hold. It should be:

```
view badLens (set badLens (1, 2) (3, 4)) ≡ (1, 2)
```

But it cannot be true, as `view badLens pair` returns some value twice: `(x, x)` for all `pair`s.

@dfeuer gives an example how to define `lensProd`.

---

Interestingly the dual is also broken. In general you cannot have lawful
sum of prism:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Lens

-- |
-- >>> :t sumPrism _Just _Nothing :: Prism' (Maybe a) (Either a ())
-- sumPrism _Just _Nothing :: Prism' (Maybe a) (Either a ())
--  :: (Applicative f, Choice p) =>
--     p (Either a ()) (f (Either a ())) -> p (Maybe a) (f (Maybe a))
--
sumPrism :: Prism' a b -> Prism' a c -> Prism' a (Either b c)
sumPrism ab ac = prism' build match where
    build (Left b)  = ab # b
    build (Right c) = ac # c

    match x = Left <$> x ^? ab <|> Right <$>  x ^? ac

-- The law
--
-- @
-- preview l (review l b) ≡ Just b
-- @
--
-- breaks with
--
-- >>> preview badPrism (review badPrism (Right 'x'))
-- Just (Left 'x')
-- 
badPrism :: Prism' a (Either a a)
badPrism = sumPrism id id
```

As you can see, we put in `Right`, but get out `Left`.

Comment: Is that really dual?

Comment: What about sum of lenses and product of prisms?

Comment: sum of lenses, like http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:choosing ?

Answer (score 8):

As phadej explained, there's no law-abiding way to do this in general. However, you can do it anyway and warn your users that they'd better be careful only to apply it to orthogonal lenses.

```
import Control.Lens
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))

fakeIt :: Lens' s x -> Lens' s y -> Lens' s (x,y)
fakeIt l1 l2 =
  lens (view l1 &&& view l2)
       (\s (x,y) -> set l1 x . set l2 y $ s)
```

For example:

```
Prelude Control.Lens A> set (fakeIt _1 _2) (7,8) (1,2,3)
(7,8,3)
Prelude Control.Lens A> view (fakeIt _1 _2) (1,2,3)
(1,2)
```

Comment: We could get a type level proof of disjointness as in compdata I imagine, and a combinator conditioned upon providing such proof